# Files are shown in Gnome Files but invisible in terminal

Tags: gnome, 22.04, files, tor-browser

I downloaded Tor browser. A text file was created everytime starting up Tor. They are empty, visible in Gnome Files with "locked" and "undeletable" icon:
[image]

but they're not shown intermial with `ls -la` command.

[image]

What are those files and how can I delete them?

Comment: is "lsattr -a" worked ?

Comment: No, it is same as ls -la